# Vue Native installed but npm start doesn't work gets a error

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, vue-native

I followed the vue native website I installed every thing what I need but when I try to run:

`npm start` or `npm run ios`

It gives me this error:

```
npm start
Debugger attached.

> @ start C:\xampp\htdocs\Karlisu
> expo start

Debugger attached.
Debugger attached.
Starting project at C:\xampp\htdocs\Karlisu
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is the package.json file:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.2.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "vue-native-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "vue-native-core": "^0.1.4",
    "vue-native-helper": "^0.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "vue-native-scripts": "^0.1.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Do you have expo installed?

Comment: @jonnycraze yes I installed

Comment: Are you running a version of node and npm that are compatible?

Comment: @jonnycraze I have version 12.16.1